# How to execute a shell script in multiple git repositories and projects?

Tags: git, shell

I need to run the below shell script to list merges and non-merged branches in multiple repos and projects. For example

```
- proj 1
   repo1    repo2    repo3

- proj 2
   repo1    repo2    repo3

- proj 3
   repo1    repo2    repo3
```

Script.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Merged branches"
for branch in `git branch -r --merged | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git log --no-merges -n 1 --format="%ci, %cr, %an, %ae, "  $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r

echo ""
echo "Not merged branches"
for branch in `git branch -r --no-merged | grep -v HEAD`;
do echo -e `git log --no-merges -n 1 --format="%ci, %cr, %an, %ae, " $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all your projects and repos checked out in a structured way, I would write a bash loop.

Let's assume you have directories `proj1`, `proj2`, etc each containing their repos, `proj1/repo1`, `pro1/repo2`, etc. Then this should work:

```
for repo in */*/.git; do
   base=`dirname $repo`
   echo Entering $base
   pushd $base
   ../../script.sh
   popd
done
```

This solution takes advantage of the fact that each Git sandbox has a `.git` directory at its root. Just using `*/*` would work if there is nothing else in your structure.

If your repos are at different depths in your directory structure, you could replace `*/*/.git` by this find command: `find . -maxdepth 3 -name .git`:

```
for repo in `find . -maxdepth 3 -name .git`; do
   ...
```

Adjust the `-maxdepth` option to grab all of your repos. You could leave it out but then `find` would pointlessly go through the contents of all your repos too.

Comment: but here i dont have names in structured manner. the project and repositories are different different. how can we do that in these scenarios?

Comment: If your project directories only have repos in them, and nothing else, using `for repo in */*` could work. If not, let me work out a solution that uses the presence of `.git` to detect repos.

Comment: There, that should be a much more general solution, with a first variant for fixed depth structures and a second variant for variable depth project structures.

Comment: Glad I could help.